# Upgrading to Angular 6, error: "Refusing to delete" ... "is outside" ..."and not a link"

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular6

I'm developing an app for the first time. I originally built it using Angular 5.2 and am trying to upgrade to Angular 6.

Per the instructions at https://update.angular.io/ I ran the following commands:
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli
ng update @angular/cli

I got an error ("Could not find a package.json. Are you in a Node project?"), and realized I am probably supposed to be doing this from within the directory that contains my project. Oops. Again, I'm super new to coding.

So I navigated to my project directory and tried again.

When running npm install @angular/cli though, I got the following error:

> npm ERR! Refusing to delete [MyProjectDirectory]/node_modules/.bin/ng: is outside [MyProjectDirectory]/node_modules/@angular/cli and not a link
>   npm ERR! File exists: [MyProjectDirectory]/node_modules/.bin/ng
>   npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

Here's the actual hosted version of the app (still on 5.2, hosted via GH pages) in case that's helpful in any way:
https://opensocialsecurity.com/

Any input about what I should do next would be super appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete the node modules directory and try again. Given error means npm is not able to delete it.
Try this command in your project directory:

`sudo rm -rf node_modules`

Comment: Thank you! I manually deleted the directory in question and ran the npm install command again and it worked.